# How can eclipse detect my Samsung Galaxy SII for USB Debugging with Debian as an OS?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, galaxy

I want to debug android applications with my Samsung Galaxy SII in eclipse with Debian as an operation system. Eclipse is not able to detect my phone and I can't access my phone in Debian (e.g. to transfer files). Eclipse is able to detect a device but the name is unknown.

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

I guess this happens because I don't have any drivers installed but I can't find Samsung Galaxy SII drivers for Linux.

I would be glad if someone can help me.

**Edit:**
When I run the command adb devices it prints:
??????????? no permissions

Comment: check if you os has drivers to support your phone

Comment: I think there are no drivers installed for my phone and I can't find any on the internet. Or how can I check whether there are drivers on my os? I'm new to linux (debian).

Comment: It would be new that on Linux there are any drivers required. Is your phone visible to adb? What does `adb devices` report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a SII but an older Samsung Model that works pretty well on debian.

Are you sure that you:

- enabled USB Debugging on your phone?

  This setting should be somewhere below Development
- created an udev rule for your device?

  As described here http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html if it's a Samsung the vendor id should be "04e8" but better check that yourself.